# ! Dimension too large error in beamer with more than 34 slides

Tags: beamer

The following code, when added to a beamer template generates the ! Dimension too large error, when the number of slides is above 34. I am not quite finding which of these macros is the culprit:

```
% Progression bar at the bottom
%--------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \color{cidacsred}% to color the progressbar
  \hspace*{-\beamer@leftmargin}%
  \rule{\beamer@leftmargin}{2pt}%
  \rlap{\rule{\dimexpr
      \beamer@startpageofframe\dimexpr
      \beamer@rightmargin+\textwidth\relax/\beamer@endpageofdocument}{1pt}}
  {}
}
```

- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to replace the first argument to `\rule` with `\dimexpr(\beamer@rightmargin+\textwidth)*\beamer@startpageofframe/\beamer@endpageofdocument\relax`.

Comment: Thank you! This works. Could you please post as an answer, breaking up a little? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the way `\dimexpr` parses dimension expressions. During any step, the intermediate dimension must not exceed 16383.99999pt (with one exception). In your case, if you have more than 34 slides, then the following will overflow:

```
\beamer@startpageofframe\dimexpr\beamer@rightmargin+\textwidth\relax
```

which, on the 35th slide, means `35*<about the width of slide>`.

We can get around this overflow, by doing a “scaling operation” instead of “first multiplying then dividing”. This is the one exception when the intermediate dimension can be as large as a 64-bit integer representation (the result has to be less than 16383.99999pt in absolute value, of course). So you can change the first argument of `\rule` to

```
\dimexpr(\beamer@rightmargin+\textwidth)
  *\beamer@startpageofframe/\beamer@endpageofdocument\relax
```

so that the multiplication and division are done as one “scaling” step.